# Json $schema only works on root object

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to use the `$schema` property in a json file to point to a local json schema file.  This works if I do it at the root:

[image]

But doesn't work if it is applied to any other element not at the root:

[image]

Is there a way to make this work when not applying the schema to the root?

Answer (score 1):

No. The JSON Schema specification doesn't permit this.*

Why do you want to do this? The `$schema` keyword is declaring the syntax to use for the entire schema. It doesn't make sense to change that halfway through.

* Technically you can use the `$schema` keyword at any place that is known as a "resource root", but if you don't know what that is, you shouldn't be making use of that feature as it's rather advanced.

Comment: I want intellisense for appsettings.json which obviously already has its own schema.  I just want to apply my schema to my 'section' of the settings.  As I've documented above, works correctly in Visual Studio (proper).

Comment: If you want this to work in VSCode, I suggest you search for existing issues on the GitHub repo, and create one if it doesn't exist. I can understand how it would be useful in the context of validating config files, but composing what schema to use at what location in this way isn't the intended use of JSON Schema. You could, in stead, create your own schema, which references the original, so you get both.

Comment: Actually, on reading the question again I wonder if the `$schema` keyword is being used in *data*, rather than a schema, which means VSCode has invented its own heuristic which is not supported by the JSON Schema standard. Also, `$schema` URIs can never be relative - they must be absolute, with a scheme e.g. "file:" or "http:".

Comment: @Ether FYI, this works in Visual Studio proper.  appsettings.jon has its schema.  I added a 'core' settings node with 'core schema' that I'd created, and a secondary 'site specific' settings node with a 'site schema'.  So there were 'three' schemas in play and it worked.  I'll go though VS Code issues and see if any mention of it.